# Do six-month or three-month passport rules apply to aufenhaltstitel holders?

Tags: germany, passport-renewals, german-residents

I am a non-EU citizen living in Germany on a residence permit (aufenhaltstitel). My passport expires in February 2024, which is also when my residence permit expires. I need to make a business trip outside the Schengen zone sometime in October or November 2023. The trip would last less than one week.

Will I be allowed to re-enter Germany after my business trip? My residence card and passport will be valid, but if I am subject to any minimum passport validity time rules, I fear that I won't satisfy them? As a resident of Germany, am I exempt from this rule?

Comment: The minimum passport validity time rules of Article 6(1) of the Schengen Border Code applies to **visitors**, not to residents.